# App won't validate. Bundle identifier differs from reserved bundle identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle, identifier

Apparently, I'm a lot worse at this app submission stuff than I thought.  My app won't validate because the "bundle identifier XXX differs from the reserved bundle identifier: YYY."  the only thing is that in my info.plist  the bundle identifier is YYY.

I changed it to match the one it was expecting from the garbage starting with "$" that XCode put there automatically.

I then deleted the build folder, and rebuilt the application.  Still, doesn't work.  I even checked the .plist in the built file itself and it's correct.

I'm at a loss.  Anybody want to shed some light on this for me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this my self.  So I know you might have this solved by now but...

On x-code 4 when archiving and validating. After the password page, Make sure your (don't assume) that the top drop down box is the right app. As when as your bundle drop down choice.

Fixed it for me.